# How to authenticate subdomains with asp.net admin tool (AspNetSqlMembershipProvider)?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, subdomain

I have have five clients on separate sub-domains. they all currently log in with AspNetSqlMembershipProvider on the back end.  with the current setup they can get to each others data if they knew the sub-domain name of the other clients.  Is there anyway to limit each person's log in access to their own sub-domain using ASP.NET ADMIN Tool ???

My only thought is to create a separate AspNetSqlMembershipProvider DB for each sub-domain\Client and point WebConfig to it but that seems wasteful.  Would like to know if there is a way to achieve the goal without creating a separate DB for every client??

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have separate applications for each sub-domain, you can use the [SqlMembershipProvider.ApplicationName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.applicationname.aspx) in your web.config to differentiate between them. This will prevent clients from one application from logging into another.

Comment: Perfect !  Thanks for the Link...helped a lot.